# Cannot Extend UDF in my Java class

Tags: java, maven, hive, pom.xml, udf

I added the following dependencies

```
Group id: org.apache.hive
Artifact id:hive-common
version:2.1.1
```

and

```
Group id: org.apache.hive
Artifact id:hive-exec
version:2.1.1
```

in my pom.xml dependency file.

I saved it and it gave me no error.
I created a Java classA

```
public class A extends UDF{

    //
}
```

But my Eclipse does not identify UDF and does not import the required packages, instead it asks me to create a UDF class.

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
```

You need that line. If that is not available, you have the wrong dependencies, or just not downloaded the sources yet.

Note: `hive-exec` is the correct dependency (and that includes `hive-common` and `hadoop-common` itself), so it's probably that Maven has not downloaded your sources.

Run a Maven `clean`, then `compile` tasks to get them.

Answer (score 0):

Please add following dependencies in your pom.xml.

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
      <version>${hive.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
      <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

After that make sure, that it is available in your maven dependecies jar folder.

UDF class is imported from below package and class :

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
```

Once you have your dependecies imported in the project, it will automatically find the classes.